# Switching object's boolean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a project where I have a object of a Task class with boolean *done*. I want to be able to switch it with a button on the website. I am not quite sure what the best practice would be to do such thing.
Should I:

1. Send a PATCH request with no body at the /doneTask/{id}/{done} and in the controller through service change the done field?
2. Send a PATCH request with JSON body?
3. Call a function on object in the Thymeleaf?
4. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who you ask... There are a couple of different ways of doing it, really just depends on what architecture you are trying to adhere to. If its REST then take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_Web_services